# Лингвистический термин

Tags: лексика

В интернете встретил задание:

В русском языке существует слово, которое часто входит в состав лингвистических терминов. У этого слова в составе терминов есть два антонима. При этом у этих антонимов одна и та же
приставка, а корни имеют противоположное значение. Что это за слово?

Ответ мне неизвестен. Может, вы знаете?

Comment: Это должно быть что-то настолько простенькое, что филологи не улавливают, прозёвывают, типа термин - частица, антонимы - да-нет, дело за приставкой... Задание для ПЕРВОГО-ЧЕТВЁРТОГО классов!

Comment: @Galina Avanesova, скорее задание из олимпиады.

Comment: Я даже просматривал термины - ничего не нашел.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я думаю, это термин **ассимиляция** (уподобление): оглушение, озвончение.

Если это задание для старшеклассников, они должны знать этот термин.

Comment: Люся, я нашла этот вопрос, обращенный к учёникам 1--4 классов, это что-то проще: звук, гласный...

Comment: А где же здесь общая приставка?  Ссылочку дайте, пожалуйста!

Comment: Вопрос я нашла без ответа, а приставку я и не предлагала (нетути). Я дала "исходник" - степень простоту задания, печку, от которой плясать. У меня есть скрин задания - я  Вам пришлю в ММ.

Comment: @Людмила  Оглушение и озвончение - это два вида ассимиляции, но это же не антонимы для слова "ассимиляция". А в задании сказано: у этого слова есть два антонима.  Как понимать эту фразу: у слова есть два антонима? Глухой и звонкий между собой антонимы, да и то с натяжкой. Глухой - только шум, а звонкий - голос и шум. Думаю, что ответ лежит где-то в стороне от звонких и глухих согласных.

Comment: Галина, а я нашла это задание на двух сайтах: Домашняя работа - https://sdelau-uroki.ru/main/order/46606/ -
 задание для 8 класса и вот ещё: https://www.liveexpert.ru/topic/view/3240117-zadanie-v-russkom-yazike-sushestvuet-slovo-kotoroe-chasto-vhodit-v-sostav-lingvisticheskih-terminov-u-etogo-slova-v-sostave-terminov-est  там Сержу что-то никто не ответил. так что это не 1 - 4 класс, а 8. Так что может быть правой и Sharon. А может быть верным и мой ответ, в 8 классе ассимиляцию-диссимиляцию учат, но называют уподобление и расподобление. А сам вопрос дейтсвительно может быть понят по-разному.

Comment: Я вот поняла, что есть какой-то термин, а в составе этого названия, в перечне того, что относится к ассимиляции, есть два антонима - оглушение и озвончение. С другой стороны, есть термин диссимиляция-расподобление, а к ней 2 антонима: оглушение и озвончение - оба антонимы к диссимиляции, потому что отражают ассимиляцию.

Comment: @Людмила, *Я вот поняла, что есть какой-то термин, а в составе этого названия,* - от безысходности можно понять и так, но это уже наши вольные  упражнения, невозможно доказать, что автор имел в выиду именно это, формально условие говорит о другом: 1) есть слово (термин) 2.. У этого слова в составе термина (?!) есть аж два антонима 3. морфологическая структура  этих антонимов удовлетворяют указанным условиям: общая приставка и антонимичные друг другу корневые морфы. Да, звучит бредовато, но строго по формулировке.

Comment: Я подумала об ассимиляции ещё и из-за формулировки "слово, которое часто входит в состав лингвистических терминов" , т.е. не всегда, а часто, а ассимиляция - термин не только лингвистики, но и этнографии, социологии (ассимиляция звуков, ассимиляция народностей). Диссимиляция тоже многозначный термин.

Answer (score 3):

> В русском языке существует слово, которое часто входит в состав
>   лингвистических терминов. У этого слова в составе терминов есть два
>   антонима. При этом у этих антонимов одна и та же приставка, а корни
>   имеют противоположное значение. Что это за слово?

Не удивлюсь, если окажется, что это задание или недостаточно корректно было составлено или же неправильно кем-то воспроизведено…

И не удивлюсь тому, что ответ мог предполагаться примерно таким:

**ГЛАСНЫЙ** звук.

Антонимом к слову ГЛАСНЫЙ в данном случае является слово СОГЛАСНЫЙ.

Ну а СОГЛАСНЫЕ звуки бывают разными — и твёрдыми, и мягкими… и   **ПОЛУТВЁРДЫМИ (ПОЛУМЯГКИМИ)**.

ПОЛУ — приставка.

ТВЁРДЫЙ, МЯГКИЙ — антонимы.

Comment: @ slava1947, ваш ответ больше всего ближе к истине. Ближе, потому что все-таки мы не можем с точностью утверждать, какое слово задумали составитили. И кстати, мне тоже кажется, что задание не совсем корректно.

Comment: Только вот неясно, какой второй антоним может быть у этих слов.

Comment: Хотелось бы знать, какие конкретно согласные в русском языке являются полумягкими и полутвердыми. До сих мне была известна такая информация (школьный вариант): 15 пар твердых/мягких согласных, Ж, Ш, Ц - только твердые, Ч, Щ, Й - только мягкие. Всего 36 согласных. Где же они, полумягкие и полутвердые, да еще изучаемые в начальной школе? Существовали когда-то  давно (до  середины XI в) в древнерусском языке полумягкие согласные, да и то не были самостоятельными фонемами, а выступали как позиционные варианты твердых.  А вот о полутвердых согласных информации и вовсе нет.

Comment: @Sharon,  вы правы о том, что пишите.

Comment: Да, наверное. Кстати, ПОЛУ - это корень, а не приставка. И еще мне кажется, что текст вопроса составлен некорректно, как будто это перевод. "Входит в состав лингвистических терминов, у  этого слова в составе терминов..." .  Что это за выражения? Как-то не по-русски звучит. Наверное, и с содержанием что-нибудь напутали.

Comment: Мне интересно, откуда это задание и почему нет ответа.

Comment: slava1947, я согласен, что авторы перемудрили с формулировкой, но не до тай же степени. Можно "полу" сдуру назвать приставкой, можно даже твердый и мягкий считать терминами, которые куда-то там входят, но какая где тут антонимы?! полумягкий и полутвердый  антонимами не являются ни  друг к другу, еи к слову звук. Слова "твердый" и "мягкий" - да, антонимы (хотя и не в лингвистике), но они-то удовлетворяют только одному требованию - на противоположное значение корней, а в условии явно говорится еще об требовании одном требовании - на антонимичность чего-то еще (чего именно - большой вопрос)..

Comment: А где два антонима ответу "гласный"? ("у этого слова... два антонима")

Comment: _behemothus: я согласен, что авторы перемудрили с формулировкой, но не до такой же степени…_ === Степень эта мне не известна. Да и Вам тоже — иначе бы Вы не написали далее: "а в условии явно говорится еще об требовании одном требовании - на антонимичность чего-то еще (**чего именно - большой вопрос**)…" Главное в моём ответе — указание на некорректность задания. Ну а далее — просто предположения… Удивило меня в Вашем комментарии это: "Можно "полу" сдуру назвать приставкой…" А если не "сдуру", то как бы Вы назвали это "полу": префиксом, префиксоидом?.. Или, как Шарон, корнем?

Comment: _Alex_ander: А где два антонима ответу "гласный"? ("у этого слова... два антонима")_ === Первый антоним: _согласный полумягкий_. Второй: _согласный полутвёрдый_. Но, повторюсь, это только мои предположения... Как именно надо понимать задание, по-моему, знает только его автор.

Answer (score 2):

Например, в некоторых языках бывают *полузвонкие* и *полуглухие* согласные:

http://www.genlingnw.ru/Staff/Kasevich/publicat/phonolog.pdf

(с. 240/418)

Второй антоним "звонкому" - в слове "*полушипящие*". Соответственно, таким словом может быть **звонкий**.

Comment: Антоним полузвонкому - полущипящий?

Comment: Нет, в вопросе антонимы - в _части_ термина, в корне. Антоним _звонкому_ - шипящий, причём не в лингвистическом смысле (такого требования в загадке нет).

Comment: А в каком значении?

Comment: И кстати, в словах звонкий и щипащий где приставки?

Comment: По условию загадки, приставка в искомое слово или его антонимы не входит. Антонимы это в бытовом значении: шипящий звук не бывает звонким.

Comment: Alex_ander, если Вам нетрудно, запишите эти три слова, чтобы их все видели. Тогда будет ясно, почему второе и третье - это антонимы для первого.

Answer (score 2):

Я согласен с Людмилой, задание надо понимать именно так, речь идет о поиске двух антонимов друг к другу, а не двух антонимов к одному исходному термину ("слову"), как можно подумать из-за безобразной формулировки.

Но фокус-то в том, что подобных терминов можно найти если не вагон с тележкой, то уж явно не один.
Помимо ***озвончающей-оглушающей ассимиляции*** вспомнились:
***повышающая-понижающая интонация***
***уменьшительный-увеличительный суффикс***
и несколько менее очевидных.

(+)
 Посмотрел по второй ссылке от Людмилы (https://www.liveexpert.ru/topic/view/3240117-zadanie-v-russkom-yazike-sushestvuet-slovo-kotoroe-chasto-vhodit-v-sostav-lingvisticheskih-terminov-u-etogo-slova-v-sostave-terminov-est).

Если считать, что приведенные там три задания из одного источника, то есть основания считать, что мы наговариваем на автора. Два других задания вполне разумно составлены.

Следовательно, надо искать именно одно слово, у которого есть два антонима с указанными признаками. Хотя такое и крайне маловероятно. Я даже вне лингвистики не могу придумать примера двух слов с одинаковыми приставками и противоположными корневыми морфами - по сути антонимами друг к другу! -  которые были бы еще антонимами к третьему слову. Невероятное сочетание трех попарно антонимичных слов.

Вот что-то такое: ***стоять - пойти/положить?***  Но это весьма слабые антонимы.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

**СИНОНИМЫ** (греч. synonymos — одноименный). Слова **близкие или тождественные по своему значению,** выражающие одно и то же понятие, но различающиеся или оттенками значения, или стилистической окраской, или и тем и другим.

**ОМОФОНЫ** (от греч. homos — одинаковый + phone — голос, звук). **Разные слова**, **одинаково звучащие**, но имеющие разное написание. Луг — лук, плод — плот, род — рот, труд омофоны трут, туш — тушь. Омофоны называют также фонетическими омонимами.

**ОМОГРАФЫ** (от греч. homos — одинаковый + grapho — пишу). **Разные слова,** совпавшие **по написанию** (но не по произношению). Замок (дворец) — замок (на двери). Мука (мучение) - мука (продукт).  Омографы называют также графическими омонимами.

Вывод:

**Синоним, омофон и омограф.**

Синоним — это **одинаковое значение**, но **разное** звучание и запись.

Омофон — это **разное значение**, но **одинаковое** звучание.

Омограф — это **разное значение,** но **одинаковая** запись.

**Примечание**

Кстати, в справочнике **для начальной школы** (серия "школьный словарик") все термины присутствуют.

Comment: А *омо* здесь разве приставка?

Comment: Это иноязычный формант, близкий по значению к приставке. Но ответ предложен как вариант, если условно считать, что это приставка.

Comment: А какие антонимы вы предлагаете к словам омографы, омофоны, синонимы?

Comment: А где _русское_ слово из вопроса?

Comment: Серж,  синоним - это сам заданный термин, у слов-синонимов одинаковое значение. Слова-омографы и слова-омофоны имеют разное значение, по этому признаку эти два термина противоположны синониму, то есть оба являются антонимами к термину "синоним". При этом у этих двух антонимов разные корни и одинаковые иноязычные приставки. Всё это в достаточной мере условно, но мне тоже интересно, каков правильный ответ. Согласитесь, что такая ситуация среди слов встречается не часто.

Comment: Alex_ander, мне неясен Ваш комментарий. В русском языке есть слово синоним, или вы думаете, что его там нет? В вопросе не говорится о русском слове, хотя этот термин достаточно условен. (Вроде бы у нас есть слова исконные и заимствованные).

Comment: Пусть это будет русское слово иноязычного происхождения - я его не нашёл в ответе (как и приставки, используемой с его корнем и двумя антонимами к значению корня).

Comment: Значит, мы по-разному понимаем вопрос. Я Ваш ответ тоже не поняла:   звонкие и шипящие - это слова из разной классификации звуков, их нельзя сравнивать в принципе.  А если я что-то не понимаю в принципе, то я и не пытаюсь это сделать.

Comment: @Alex_ander, мы как раз и ищем румское слово из вопроса.

Comment: @Sharon, я не считаю правильным противопоставлять синонимы омографом и омонимам. Кстати, в  русском языке у этих слов приставка не выделяется.

Comment: @Sharon В задании не говорится о лигвистическом понимании антонимов и их месте в классификации, как и о строгой противоположности слов по значению. Достаточно того, что шипящий звук в бытовом понимании не может быть звонким. Предлагалось найти ровно одно слово, которое подпадает под перечисленные условия.

Comment: Серж, я уже ответила на все эти вопросы: про приставку, которая не приставка, и про всё прочее, что мне кажется ясным, а другим нет. Кажется, лучшее, что я могу сделать, - это убрать ответ, который никому не нравится.  Единственное, почему мне не хочется этого сейчас же сделать, это любопытство: а где же он, ясный и правильный? Я сильно сомневаюсь, что такой ответ  отыщется среди шипящих и звонких звуков. И среди полуглухих и полузвонких тоже (причем в некоторых языках).

Answer (score 1):

Просмотрел тему…

А хороший вариант Людмила предложила — в комментариях к своему ответу!

**ДИССИМИЛЯЦИЯ**

с антонимами

ОГЛУШЕНИЕ (ассимиляция по глухости) и

ОЗВОНЧЕНИЕ (ассимиляция по звонкости).

Answer (score 0):

Долго думая над этим заданием, я пришла к умозаключению, что это *"троп",* так как в составе терминов этого слова есть преувеличение и приуменьшение (литота и гипербола).

Comment: Строго говоря, литота и гибербола - не антонимы.